# Comparing two nested JSON structures

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare two JSON structures by their keys, not the values inside the keys.

The goal is to see if the one is different by the other. I don't need a diff, just a simple flag. I've tried to do it but somehow I can't get a solution that would not be overcomplicated.

Sample JSON1 structure

```
{ "parentKey" : 
    { "childKey" : { "nestedKey" : "value" }, 
      "childKey2: "value2" }}
```

JSON2

```
{ "parentKey" : 
    { "childKey" : { "nestedKey" : "value2", 
                     "nestedKey2": "value3"}, 
      "childKey2: "value2" }}
```

Comment: Please provide some examples to explain what you mean.

Comment: 'If one is different by the other' If some keys are different?  If the whole structure is different ? You probably can use a `for in` but you need to provide some more details

Comment: @iota I've updated question. Basically trying to do a deep compare on two objects keys without comparing values.

Comment: @Radu they are different if they have different structure and the keys

Comment: Take a look into a library called lodash

Comment: "I've tried to do it but somehow"  Please include this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to see if the 2 objects are not exactly identical (just the keys, not the values) It's pretty simple, you just check Every key in both objects. If you need to know what key is different or how is different it's entirely a different problem.

```js
let o1 = { "parentKey" : 
    { "childKey" : { "nestedKey" : "value" }, 
      "childKey2": "value2" }}
      
let o2 = { "parentKey" : 
    { "childKey" : { "nestedKey" : "value2", 
                     "nestedKey2": "value3"}, 
      "childKey2": "value2" }}

  let keysInObj1 = []
  let keysInObj2 = []
  
     function compare(object, arr){
       for (const obj in object){
         arr.push(obj)
            if(typeof(object[obj]) == 'object'){
              compare(object[obj], arr)         
            }
        }
     }

     compare(o1, keysInObj1)
     compare(o2, keysInObj2)


keysInObj1.forEach((val, index)=>{
    if(keysInObj2[index] != val){
         console.log('Objects are not the same')
    }
})
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzx4fdtr/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan#readme)

This solution could easily be modified to tell you exactly the keys that the objects are different.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const d1 = { parentKey: { childKey: { nestedKey: 'value' }, childKey2: 'value2' } };
const d2 = { parentKey: { childKey: { nestedKey: 'value2', nestedKey2: 'value3' }, childKey2: 'value2' } };

const cmp = (a, b) => {
  const r1 = objectScan(['**'], { joined: true })(a);
  const r2 = objectScan(['**'], { joined: true })(b);
  if (r1.length !== r2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  return r1.every((e) => r2.includes(e));
};

console.log(cmp(d1, d2));
// => false

console.log(cmp(d1, d1));
// => true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.3.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const compareKeys = (obj1, obj2) =>
  Object.keys(obj1).length === Object.keys(obj2).length &&
  Object.keys(obj1).every((key) => key in obj2);

var object1 = {
  "banana": "bar",
  "orange": "foo"
};

var object2 = {
  "banana": "foo",
  "orange": "bar"
};

var object3 = {
  "aaaaa": "bar",
  "jjjjj": "foo"
};

//Expected output: true
console.log(compareKeys(object1, object2));
//Expected output: false
console.log(compareKeys(object1, object3));
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried this approach keep in mind the structure should be same too.

Therefore,

```
 {name: "Anuj", isTaxPayer: true}
 {isTaxPayer: true, name: "Shonster"}
```

will not be same

```js
var keys1 = [];
var keys2 = [];
var json1 = { "parentKey" : 
    { "childKey" : { "nestedKey" : "value" }, 
      "childKey2": "value2" }};
var json2 = { "parentKey" : 
    { "childKey" : { "nestedKey" : "value2", 
                     "nestedKey2": "value3"}, 
      "childKey2": "value2" }};

function getKeys(Obj, res){
        res === undefined ? res = [] : 1;
        for(prop in Obj){
            res.push(prop);
            if(Object.prototype.toString.call(Obj[prop]).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1] === "Object"){
                getKeys(Obj[prop], res);
            }
        }
        return res;
}

function isDifferent(){
    keys1 = getKeys(json1).join("").toLowerCase();
        keys2 = getKeys(json2).join("").toLowerCase();
    keys1 === keys2 ? alert("SAME") : alert("NOPE");
}

isDifferent();
```